# How to insert Mysql Data text on Object [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello such first of all thank you for your help friends.

I would like to see if they can help me with this problem, I'm inserting routes latitude and longitude of Google Maps incluyendole a capo text input called "pathname" in my database, all very well to insert the latitude and longitude, but when you insert the "pathname" I returned in the cast of the pathname field inserccionen "[object HTMLCollection]"
What I want is to insert text or value of that input.

Below is my code to see if they can give me a hand you'll be thanked

**Php Code Index.php:**

```
<?php 
      $lat = "18.472848374914534";
      $lng = "-69.92593261718753";
      $pos = $_POST ["pos"];
      $nombre_ruta = $_POST ["nombre_ruta"];
      echo "
      <div id='info' name='info' class='info'>".$pos."</div>
      <div id='seleccion_mapa'></div>
      <input type='text' name='nombre_ruta' id='nombre_ruta' placeholder='ponga aqui, el nombre de la ruta' class='Txt_SELECCIONAR' />
      <input type='submit' id='enviar' name='enviar' value='CREAR RUTA' class='Txt_btn_submit2' value='CREAR RUTA'>
      <br>
      <div id='respuesta'></div>";
      ?>
```

**js Script Ajax**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      lat = "<?php echo $lat; ?>" ;
      lng = "<?php echo $lng; ?>" ;
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 7,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("seleccion_mapa"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          draggable:true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          web:"Localización geográfica!",
          icon: "../../../../assets/img/marker.png"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
          var myLatLng = event.latLng;
          lat = myLatLng.lat();
          lng = myLatLng.lng();
          nombre_ruta = myLatLng.nombre_ruta();
          document.getElementByTagId('info').innerHTML = [
          lat,
          lng,
          nombre_ruta
          ].join(', ');
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      $("#enviar").click(function() { 
        var url = "../../../controllers/cargar_mapa.php";
        $("#respuesta").html('<img src="../../../../assets/img/loading17.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: 'lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng + '&nombre_ruta=' + nombre_ruta ,
         success: function(data)
         {
           $("#respuesta").html(data);
         }
       });
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

**and database insert code**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
include('../../Connections/conexion_mapa_ruta.php');
    $lat=strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lat']));
    $lng=strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lng']));
    $nombre_ruta=$_POST['nombre_ruta'];
    $pos=$lat.",".$lng;
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ruta_transporte (Lat, Lng, Pos, nombre_ruta) values ('$lat','$lng','$pos','$nombre_ruta')");
    echo "<b> Posición guardada: </b>".$nombre_ruta.",".$lat.", ".$lng;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your POST data client-side:

```
data: 'lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng + '&nombre_ruta=' + nombre_ruta
```

`nombre_ruta` is an object.  Possibly from when it's set here?:

```
nombre_ruta = myLatLng.nombre_ruta();
```

I'm really not sure what that method is returning, you may need to debug in your browser to find out.  But the point is that, whatever is in that variable, it's an object.  And since you're trying to build a string from it, the string representation of an object is exactly what you see:

> [object HTMLCollection]

Since you're building a string of key/value pairs, and since your server-side code expects to handle a string (by inserting it into a text column in a database), you're going to want to make sure your variable is set to a simple string value before POSTing that value.

What that string value needs to be, that's up to you.  Maybe some property on the object you have?  (Not sure how likely that is, I'm still very unclear on why the Google Maps API would have a `nombre_ruta()` method on an event property, or why that method would return an `HTMLCollection` object.  You're *probably* going to have to do some more debugging, there could be more going on than what's presented in the question.)

Comment: Hi thanks David for your clarification, currently, what I try to do is get on the same insert, to my database, values in text sent by post, such as the nombre_ruta(); It is a text field o insert the name in other columns accompanied with the latitude and longitude